# Need help finding Arabic version of this Hadith from Musnad Ahmad

Tags: hadith, salat, source-identification, sahaba

Salaam,

I came across the following hadith online and was hoping someone could include the arabic version that I believe is found in Musnad Ahmad.  The entire Musnad Ahmad hasn't been translated in English online yet for us to view (though I know it is available in book format).  JazakAllah khair for the help.

Ahmad (9504) narrated that Abu Hurayrah (may Allah be pleased with him) said: The Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) led us in praying Zuhr, and in the last row there was a man who prayed badly. When he said the salaam, the Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) called him and said: “O So and so, do you not fear Allah? Do you not see how you pray. You think that you could hide from me some of what you do, but by Allah I can see behind me as well as I can see in front of me.”

Answer (score 1):

If you search for the hadith on a search engine (such as google), among the top results you find is [islamqa.info](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/199749/). The fatwas on islamqa.info are often multilingual and almost always there is an Arabic version available. You can select the Arabic version by clicking the appropriate option at the top right:

[image]

Then you have the same fatwa in Arabic language. Here you can find the Arabic text of the hadith:

> وروى أحمد (9504) عن أبي هريرة رضي الله عنه قال : " صلى بنا رسول الله عليه وسلم الظهر ، وفي مؤخر الصفوف رجل ، فأساء الصلاة ، فلما سلم ناداه رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم : ( يا فلان : ألا تتقي الله ألا ترى كيف تصلي ، إنكم ترون أنه يخفى علي شيء مما تصنعون ، والله إني لأرى من خلفي ، كما أرى من بين يدي )

Comment: JazakAllah khair for the help!